# c# Activator.CreateInstance cannot catch exception from instantiated class if I pass argument

Tags: c#, exception

I use Activator.CreateInstance to instantiate dynamic class, my class constructor generate Exception if issue appears.

When I use the parameterless constructor (Test 1), I can catch the exception launch by the instantiated class around the CreateInstance.

But, if I use constructor with argument, the exception is not catch by the try catch around the CreateInstance.

How I can catch this exception ?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public abstract class Base
    {
        public Base()
        {
            throw new Exception(" -= TEST = Bad filename. =- ");
        }

        public Base( String filename)
        {
            throw new Exception(" -= TEST = Bad filename. =- ");
        }
    }

    public class Child : Base
    {
        public Child()
            : base()
        {

        }

        public Child(String filename)
            : base(filename)
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Base child = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Child));
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test 1 (no argument): Catch OK");        
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Test 1: OK\n--------------------------");
            Console.ReadKey();

            try
            {
                Base child = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Child), "foo");
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test 2 (with argument): Catch OK");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The end");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce this. Are you on Mono, perhaps? What version of .NET are you using? And OS? Most likely your real code shows a different error than the sample code (which is fine); you'll have to find the reproducible error, or we can't help you.

Comment: Can't reproduce it as well (.NET 4.5.2).

Comment: I use .Net 4.5 , Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8.1. The sample generate an unhandled exception.

Comment: Did you actually run the code you posted, to make sure it reproduces the problem that led you to the question in the first place? There's nothing in this code that should lead to the behavior you report, and indeed the code you posted does not reproduce the problem. It's a nice code example, but it fails the key criteria that it _must_ reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes I ran it. On my environment, the Test 1 is OK, and when I hit a key to run the Test 2, VisualStudio show the dialog box :  unhandled exception about this section:

    `public Base( String filename)
     {
            throw new Exception(" -= TEST = Bad filename. =- ");
     }`

I made this sample from my real program, where the issue appears.
I am updating to .Net Framework 4.5.2 perhaps a 4.5 bug.